# Flask Multithreading with Python

Tags: flask

I am just wondering is it possible to start two functions to work in same time with Flask server? I need to start `function_1` after it trigger `function_2` and run both functions in same time. Is it possible?

```
def function_1():
    yield "start_function_2"
    counter = 0
    while True:
       counter += 1
       print counter


def function_2():
    second_counter = 0
    while True:
       second_counter += 1
       print second_counter

def main():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/start_functions", methods=["POST"])
def start_functions():
    data = request.data
    if request.method == "POST":
        for i in function_1(data):
           if (i == "start_function_2"):
              function_2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(dhost="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can. You just need to import the `threading` module.

```
import threading

def function1():
    # your code here

def function2():
   # your code here
```

You start threads like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=function1).start()
threading.Thread(target=function2).start()
```

Both will live at the same time

You can find nice tutorial [over there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) for further explanations :)

Comment: This is the most concise, helpful answer.